# Flutter How to Pop out page automatically according to stream event?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-state

I want to pop out a music player page when the audio stream is stopped. But I am getting error like

```
Unhandled Exception: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe
```

This is my code which I have placed inside the build method before returning scaffold.

```
AudioService.playbackStateStream.listen((event) {
      if (event?.processingState == AudioProcessingState.stopped) {
        
        try {
          final modal = ModalRoute.of(context);
          if (modal.isCurrent) {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          }
        } catch (e) {
          print("exception error in player adv $e");
        }
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving that to `initState()` it's possible that everytime the widget rebuilds, the listener is added, therefore you end up having multiple listeners and when triggered would call `pop` multiple times

Comment: After shifting the listener to initState() I am getting `NoSuchMethodError: The method 'dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType was called on null error occured.`

Comment: Try stopping the build and building afresh. If that doesn't help errors usually have links to the line of code causing it, might give a better clue